# how can i run tf get command in TEE-CLC-10.0.0

Tags: team-explorer-everywhere

i m using Team Explorer Everywhere and i want to run tf get command but i m unable to run this. except this i m able to run tf history, tf workfold, tf workspace.
but not tf get. it's showinf error `An argument error occurred: Items must reside in a workspace that has been previously used on this computer.` actually i m running this command `C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\Java_v3_Script_F_RINS>tf get C:/V3_WorkAreas/F_RINS_40143/ICTS/src/com/tradecapture/icts/apps/admin/control/common/AdminCache.java /force /rec
ursive /noprompt /force /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/Symphony`

Answer (score 1):

Step:1 Creating Profile

C:\Program Files\TEE-CLC-10.0.0>`tf profile /new -string:serverUrl=http://myserver:8080/tfs/symphony/ Build`

Profile 'Build' edited (1 property changed).

Step:2 Creating Workspace

C:\Program Files\TEE-CLC-10.0.0>`tf workspace /new Builds;Build /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/symphony`

Workspace 'Builds' created.

Step:3 mapping Local Folders

C:\Program Files\TEE-CLC-10.0.0>`tf workfold /map $/S/B/F_RINS/DBScripts C:\temp\Db /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/symphony /workspace:builds /login:build@tc.com,G0amphor!`